# Plot axis name on a different position other than the middle of the axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, graphics

I would like to use ggplot to plot a graph that looks similar to this, where the axis names (represented as the units) are shown along the axes instead of right in the middle of the axes.

[image: graph with units]

The only R way I can think of is to add a text object, but that may causes alignment inconsistencies if I want to display a few similar graphs together. Editing after the figure has been produced also does not seem elegant because the same editing software's font (say ppt editors) may not look the same as the same font in R.

Is there another way to achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you looked through the [theme arguments](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/theme.html)? You can adjust the angle and justification of `axis.title.x` and `axis.title.y`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what worked for me.

```r
library(ggplot2)

base <- ggplot(economics, aes(date, psavert)) +
 geom_blank() + 
  labs(x="KG", y="%")

base + theme(axis.title.y = element_text(hjust = 1, size = 14), axis.title.x = element_text( hjust = 1, size = 14))
```

[image: axis_title_position]

The default values for `axis.title.y = element_text( hjust = .5)` and `axis.title.x = element_text( hjust = .5)`, and changing the `hjust` to `0` will bring the axis texts to the co-ordinate point (0,0).

## Update

To replicate the background and the arrow, you can do as follows:

```r
# see ?ggplot2::arrow
arrow <- arrow(length = unit(0.5, "cm"), ends = "last", type = "closed")
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------

# A reproducible dataset from ggplot2 (you can use your own data set)
base <- ggplot(economics, aes(date, psavert)) +
  geom_blank() + 
  labs(x="Kg", y="%") +
  theme_bw() 
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Add a theme layer removing boarder, grid lines and add the axes arrow 
base_bg <- base + theme(
    panel.border = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    axis.line = element_line(arrow = arrow)
  )
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------

# finally position the axis title up to the arrow
base_bg + theme(axis.title.y = element_text(hjust = 1, size = 14, face="bold", family = "TT Times New Roman"), axis.title.x = element_text( hjust = 1, size = 14, face = "bold", family="Serif"))
```

## Output

[image: axis_background_replicate]

## Update - correcting `%` on Y-axis

```r
#see the addition of angle = 360 on axis.title.y
base_bg + theme(axis.title.y = element_text(hjust = 1, size = 14, face="bold", family = "TT Times New Roman", angle = 360), axis.title.x = element_text( hjust = 1, size = 14, face = "bold", family="Serif"))
```

## Output - label '%' corrected

[image: output_percent]

Comment: Thanks! I have given an upvote. But I could not get the percentage sign to show up properly - it appears at the bottom when rotated 180 degrees. Is there any way to show it as % instead of the mirror image?

Comment: @timing, add `angle = 360` to the `axis.title.y` and it'll give you what you want.

Comment: Yup it worked thanks. It is still a mystery to me why rotating 360 degrees will produce a different shape...

Comment: I think the rotation is within the y-axis and there might be a better explanation and if you use `angel=0`, it will produce the same result. Negative values such as -180 will take the label down the vertex.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```r
mop + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(margin=margin(1,2,3,4,"pt"),angle=0)
```

where 1,2,3,4 indicates the measurements of *bottom, left, top, right* margins

Comment: Few issues with your answer: look at the docs for `margin`: arguments are top, right, bottom, left, not the order you said. `axis.text.x` is the text for break labels, not axis titles. The margin also doesn't change the position of the title along the axis, just within a relatively small area where that element is already assumed to be

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hjust` to move the axis label along the line, with 1 being the max.

```
p + theme(axis.title.x = element_text(hjust = 1), axis.title.y = element_text(hjust = 1, angle = 0))
```